# Preventing applications from being closed on terminal exit

Tags: 10.04, gnome-terminal

When I close a terminal it closes all programs opened from it. In other Linux packages such as scientific linux using an ampersand prevents this, e.g., emacs file.txt & 
However, this is not the case with ubuntu 10.04. 
Is there away to stop the applications like emacs being closed on exit of the terminal?
I have tried nohup but this dosen't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `disown`. For example, `emacs file.txt & disown` After that, exiting terminal won't exit the program started from it.

Comment: Thanks 'disown' works well. I will be typing that after most things.